# Analytics Ecommerce dataLayer event not firing

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I want to setup Analytics Ecommerce with GTM.
I have created the below event that fires before the GTM snippet. Inspecting the Thank You Page with the GTM console shows that the event did not fire. What could be the problem here? Baybe syntax?

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
    'transactionId': '000000217',
    'transactionAffiliation': '',
    'transactionTotal': 32.8,
    'transactionTax': 0,
    'transactionShipping': 0,
    'transactionProducts': [
                    {
        'sku': '4091-09',
        'name': 'Tapet colectia Ideea  cod 4091-09',
        'category': 'Tapet decorativ',
        'price': 32.8,
        'quantity': 1            },
                ],
    'event': 'transactionComplete'
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only potential syntax issue I see is you have a trailing comma with the object in the transactionProducts array. That may fail in some older browsers.

Otherwise, that syntax looks good and when tested on a site that uses GTM and dataLayer, I see it added to the dataLayer array after executing it in the console.

Without knowing more, my only other suggestion would be to double check there is no `dataLayer = [];` between the code you provided and when GTM loads.

Comment: I have this code that runs between the transactionComplete event and the GTM: `dataLayer = [];;dataLayer.push({"event":"purchase","value":32.8,"items":[{"id":"289","google_business_vertical":"custom"}]})` What is your suggestion?

Comment: Do you think that changing the syntax of the above code (in the comment) to:  `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({"event":"purchase","value":32.8,"items":[{"id":"289","google_business_vertical":"custom"}]})`  will solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, the code you currently have live is clearing the data layer, the second code snippet will solve the issue.